# Define a main function in python which can run other functions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `file1.py` file which has a function.

```
def func1(x):
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return x
```

I also have a dataframe `df`.

I am running this function using `.apply function`

```
df['col1'].apply(func1)
```

but for that I have to open the `.py` file and run it.

I want to run `.py` file from command line, such that it directly goes to `df['col1'].apply(func1)`

So I wanted to define a main function which will run my `df['col1'].apply(func1)`

My knowledge to python is very limited, is there any way to do it?

Comment: `python file.py`??

Answer (score 2):

You can put it like this in `file1.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

def func1(x):
    x = x * 2
    return x

print df.apply(func1)
```

Then run from the command line:

```
python file1.py
```